# How to check if a position inside a std string exists ?? (c++)

Tags: c++, string, std

i have a long string variable and i want to search in it for specific words and limit text according to thoses words.

Say i have the following text :

"*This amazing new wearable audio solution features a working speaker embedded into the front of the shirt and can play music or sound effects appropriate for any situation. It's just like starring in your own movie*"

and the words : "solution" , "movie".

I want to substract from the big string (like google in results page):

"...new wearable audio **solution** features a working speaker embedded..."
and
"...just like starring in your own **movie**"

for that i'm using the code :

```
for (std::vector<string>::iterator it = words.begin(); it != words.end(); ++it)
{
    int loc1 = (int)desc.find( *it, 0 );    
    if( loc1 != string::npos )
    {
        while(desc.at(loc1-i) && i<=80)
        {       
            i++;
            from=loc1-i;
            if(i==80) fromdots=true;
        }
        i=0;
        while(desc.at(loc1+(int)(*it).size()+i) && i<=80)
        {
            i++;
            to=loc1+(int)(*it).size()+i;
            if(i==80) todots=true;
        }

        for(int i=from;i<=to;i++)
        {    
            if(fromdots) mini+="...";
            mini+=desc.at(i);
            if(todots) mini+="...";    
        }    
      }
```

but desc.at(loc1-i) causes OutOfRange exception... I don't know how to check if that position exists without causing an exception !

Help please!

Comment: What's with the insane level of indentation? Please make your code easier to read, so that people don't have to work so hard to help you.

Comment: You mean you want to remove from the text any of the given strings?

Comment: Oh i'm sorry, i spent time formating it but apparrently it's not clear.. i'm working on it sorry ;)

Comment: He wants to remove all sections of text that are more that N words away from any occurrences of the given strings.

Comment: @yox: I meant your indentation within the code, just like Marcelo commented on. I'll delete my comment as it's a little redundant.

Comment: @wallacoloo that's exactly what i want to do.. sorry for the bad text formatting =)

Comment: I made the indentation saner.  The opening and closing braces don't match, but I think this was the case in the original code, too.  Or I messed up.  Regardless, this is much more readable than the original mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an excellent exercise in taking advantage of what the STL has to offer. You simply open a [reference](http://cplusplus.com/reference/) and cherry-pick algorithms and classes for your solution!

```
#include <iostream> // algorithm,string,list,cctype,functional,boost/assign.hpp
using namespace std;

struct remove_from {
    remove_from(string& text) : text(text) { }
    void operator()(const string& str) {
        typedef string::iterator striter;
        striter e(search(text.begin(), text.end(), str.begin(), str.end()));
        while( e != text.end() ) {
            striter b = e;
            advance(e, str.length());
            e = find_if(e, text.end(), not1(ptr_fun<int,int>(isspace)));
            text.erase(b, e);
            e = search(text.begin(), text.end(), str.begin(), str.end());
        }
    }
private:
    string& text;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    list<string> toremove = boost::assign::list_of("solution")("movie");
    string text("This amazing new wearable ...");
    for_each(toremove.begin(), toremove.end(), remove_from(text));
    cout << text << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just check desc.size() - if it's less than the index you're looking up + 1 then you'll get an exception

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you start iterating at the first word, then try and check the word before it, hence the OutOfRange Exception.

Your first if could be:

```
if( loc1 != string::npos && loc1 != 0)
```